# What features of a website can be OS dependent?

Tags: cross-browser, operating-system

Some websites claim to 'not support Linux', but appear to work fine when I browse them from a Linux box. One such site refuses to allow me to log in when my User Agent String advertises that I'm running Linux, but works perfectly fine when I use the User Agent Switcher add-on in Firefox.

What features of a website could be OS specific?

If a website is designed to work on a particular browser, should it work on that browser regardless of the underlying OS?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774021/is-the-website-rendering-os-dependent) suggests that rendering may be platform dependent. Is it likely that rendering differences would be significant enough to make a website unusable under a certain OS?

Are there more fundamental ways in which it could be OS dependent?

Comment: There is a difference between "does not work" and "not supported": the latter just says that if it doesn't work, the developers will not do extra effort to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website should look fine under same browser version in various OSs. There are things like **location services** that can be disabled on your OS completely, or java and flash applets but mostly they are cross-platform.

Howerver, a shining example is **Silverlight** that is not supported on Linux so pages relying on it (e.g. Netflix) will not work on Linux.

Mostly its just laziness of staff to test website on linux and thus they simply state that its not supported to avoid complaints from users.